# Attempt to read from command line, if not, prompt

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to have my program attempt to read a file name from the command line, but if the user doesn't type anything into the command line, it prompts and asks for a file instead. Prompting the user is simple enough but I'm having trouble figuring out how to have both, I feel like I will run into trouble once I have to use my countBrackets(in) method because I can't declare the variable in twice

```
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
  {
    File inputFile;

    do{
      Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("enter file:");
      String fileName=console.next();
      inputFile=new File(fileName);
      Scanner in=new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      countBrackets(in);
    }while(!inputFile.exists());
  }
```

Comment: When you say 'from the command line', do you mean filename passed as an argument?

Comment: yes, "run classname file.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
if(args[0]!=null&&!args[0].isEmpty()){
      inputFile=new File(args[0]);
}

if(inputFile==null){
   do{
       Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("enter file:");
       String fileName=console.next();
       inputFile=new File(fileName);
       Scanner in=new Scanner(new File(fileName));
       countBrackets(in);
    }while(!inputFile.exists());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the length of `args`. If it is 0 then it means user did not pass anything.

You should do it as shown below:

```
int firstArg;
if (args.length > 0) {
    try {
        firstArg = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Argument" + " must be an integer");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

The tutorial is here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html